# How to delete 200k files from a directory in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a PaaS instance of Azure server.

*I have to delete around 200k files from a directory.*

I cannot delete the files from FTP Client as it will take a lot of time. What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean you have 200K files on the server?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes, log files.

Comment: What you could do is connect to the PaaS instance using Remote Desktop Connection and delete the files. Will that work for you?

Comment: @GauravMantri I only have the FTP URL of PaaS instance.

Comment: Can you please tell how the application is deployed: WebApp or Cloud Service? I made an assumption that it is deployed as a Cloud Service.

Comment: @GauravMantri WebApp.

Comment: Aah...Please discard my comment about RDP as that option is not available to you. One thing you could do is connect to the web app instance using Kudu console and from there you should be able to delete the files. Please see this blog post for more details: http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/

Answer (score 1):

Create a web job to delete those log files. Also this way you can schedule the job to delete log files older than X days.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/